# "Master" not defined within class instance

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, instance, tkinter-entry

Im trying to pass an instance of an class to which i can retrieve a function, however i keep on recieving "master" not defined when i run the program. What am i doing wrong?

```
class MainPageGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Jans Corp")
        self.master.configure(background='lightgrey')
        self.master.geometry("1200x800")

        self.DisplayData()

    def DisplayData(self):
        self.ReturnedData = Database(master) # <----------- I am recieving error here
        self.ReturnedData = getattr(self.ReturnedData, 'ReadData')
        for index, data in enumerate(self.ReturnedData):
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[0]).grid(row = index+1, column = 0)
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[1]).grid(row = index+1, column = 1)
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[2]).grid(row = index+1, column = 2)
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[3]).grid(row = index+1, column = 3)
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[4]).grid(row = index+1, column = 4)
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[5]).grid(row = index+1, column = 5)
            tk.Label(self.master, text = data[6]).grid(row = index+1, column = 6)
```

Here is where im using calling the function from

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, master):

        conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Employees (
                        FirstName text,
                        Surname text,
                        Age Integer,
                        Postcode VARCHAR,
                        Wage Integer,
                        Email VARCHAR,
                        Hours Integer
                        )""")

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        EmployeeInfo = MainPageGUI(master) <----------- Here i added master
        db = Database()
        db.addEmployee(EmployeeInfo)


    def ReadData(self):
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM Employees")
        return c.fetchall()

    def addEmployees(self , EmployeeInfo): #replace emp with the employees the users add from the entry function
        with conn:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (:FirstName, :Surname, :Age, :Postcode, :Wage, :Email, :Hours)",
                      {'FirstName':EmployeeInfo.FirstNameEntry.get(), 'Surname':EmployeeInfo.SurnameEntry.get(), 'Age':EmployeeInfo.AgeEntry.get(),
                      'postcode':EmployeeInfo.PostcodeEntry.get(), 'Wage':EmployeeInfo.EmailEntry.get(), 'Email':EmployeeInfo.EmailEntry.get(), 'Hours':EmployeeInfo.HoursEntry.get()})
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: In that function there is no `master`. There is, however, `self.master`. Either pass it in as a parameter, or use the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You got some major problems here, first replace `master` with `self` on the line where you got the error.  You can only have one of the classes be the master. 
 Then the `init` function for `Database` is all messed up.  You basically created two recursion errors.

Say you create a `Database` object.  That would create a new `MainPageGUI` object, which would then go and create another `Database` object, which would create another `MainPageGUI`.  That's one of the recursion errors

The other recursion error happens in the `Database` class.  When you define a new `Database` object it will, in its own `init` function, create another `Database` object, which will create another `Database` object...

A fixed `init` should look something like this:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, master):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Employees (
                        FirstName text,
                        Surname text,
                        Age Integer,
                        Postcode VARCHAR,
                        Wage Integer,
                        Email VARCHAR,
                        Hours Integer
                        )""")

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        self.addEmployee(master)
```

Comment: When i add `self.master` recursion happens

Comment: @hiihihihelloo: The recursion happens because `MainPageGUI` creates a `Database` instance, but `Database` also creates a new `MainPageGUI`. You need to decide which direction that should work in, and get rid of the creation going in the other direction. If both objects need a reference to the other, have one pass a reference to itself to the other one, rather than a reference to `master`.